# installing gazbo_ros package

Tags: ros, gazebo, gazebo-4

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have ubuntu 14.04 and am using **ros_indigo**. I am following tutorials from this [link](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_installing&cat=connect_ros) to connect gazebo to ros.

I have installled gazebo4 and when I am following the tutorials stated, it doesn't allow me to proceed. Apparently, it keeps forcing me to install gazebo2, which forces me to remove gazebo4.How can I have them both? For eg : I am using drcsim as well, which means I would atleast require gazebo4.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9273/installing-gazbo_ros-package/) by [Tonystark124](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1321/tonystark124/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you want to use ros indigo with a **gazebo version!=2.2** you should not install the meta package **ros-indigo-desktop-full**(I prefer **ros-indigo-desktop** instead). Otherwise removing gazebo2.2 will remove most of your ros installation. You will although need to install third Party packages from source instead of via apt...

If you want to use multiple versions in parallel; installing one version of ros in user space and only loading it on demand might be the way to go. But changing this might have side effects on ros packages. So you should always make sure to link against the right installation...

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2015-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1321/tonystark124/) on 2015-09-07**:
thank you for the answer. is there any restriction in using gazebo in a 32 bit machine?

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2015-09-07**:
I never tried it, sorry...
You might want to ask this in as new question if you need to know.

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1321/tonystark124/) on 2015-09-07**:
I am trying to use hector quad, in a new world I created. Do I need 2.2 for that or can I spawn hector in the new world 4 I created.?

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2015-09-07**:
I use this packages and it should work(I'm using gazebo5 at the moment..). you will have to compile them form source(Put them into your catkin workspace) But I don't see any reasons for them not to run...

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1321/tonystark124/) on 2015-09-07**:
they are running fine. My doubt was how to spawn the hector quad into a custom world I created using gazebo4 and use it there?

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2015-09-08**:
The hector_quadrotor_gazebo package has a set of launch files which you can use. If you need to specify a position you can with the provided command line args...